# joyplots no longer work after update to ggjoy

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, render, ridgeline-plot

I had a few joyplots inside my Shiny app which had worked fine when I wrote them. However, now they all show up as blank plots.

For example, one of my plots has the following code:

```
PR2016_height_joy <- ggplot(subset(arranged_PR2016_demo_data, CORAL_CD %in% PR2016_joy_vector), aes(x = HEIGHT, y = CORAL_CD)) +
  geom_joy(scale = 3, fill = "darkblue") +
  xlab("Height (cm)") +
  ylab("Species") +
  ggtitle(region) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

And that now renders the warning:

`` Warning: Computation failed in `stat_joy()`: unused arguments (bw = bandwidth, from = min, to = max, na.rm = TRUE) ``

And the plot is just a blank plot. Is a similar issue happening for anyone else?

Comment: Could you share you dataset `arranged_PR2016_demo_data` and `PR2016_joy_vector`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe I can. I was hoping the issue would not be related to the data itself (or could be resolved without it), but if it is I apologize for not asking a reproducible question.